# GTK/GDK Algorithm to take full screenshots of all monitors

Tags: linux, gtk, screenshot, gdk

I'm fairly new to the whole GTK game and want to create an algorithm to take screen shot of all monitors.

I was thinking something along these lines:

1. `gdk_display_manager_list_displays`
2. each display can have multiple screens (screens means monitors?) so use `gdk_display_get_n_screens` to get monitors per display from `1`
3. get root gtk window of all screens from `2`
4. create new Pixbuf for each root gtk window for each screen from `3` with `gdk_pixbuf_new`
5. fill each pixbuf from `4` with `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` for each respective root window from `3` for each respective screen from `2` for each respective display from `1` (may need to `gdk_drawable_get_size` and `gdk_window_get_origin` for each for args to pixbuf)
6. `gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels` for each pixbuf

Is this a workable solution?

Comment: I think it can work. Here is a link: http://git.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screenshooter/tree/lib/screenshooter-capture.c#n325

Comment: Thanks @ntd ! I wrote this version up here in js-ctypes: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/gdk-experimental/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L439-506  however its getting null when i try gdk3 method of `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window` and its crashing when i try gdk2 method of `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` :(

Comment: My comment was too long so I posted an answer. I think the solution will involve a lot of trial and error on your side though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure `cRootWin` is not NULL and `cWidth` and `cHeight` are greater than 0 then you should check for some additional problem mentioned [by the doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Pixbufs.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-from-window).

A wild guess is your program does not have enough memory to store the pixmap (typically 6 Mb). I would try to allocate the 12 Mb just to see if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks @ntd!! This helps ill update you on progres! :)